# Error after update to Subversion 1.8.3

Tags: svn, ubuntu

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load:
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so: undefined symbol: dav_svn_get_repos_path
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I get this error after updating SVN on Ubunutu (12.10 Quantal) when I try to restart the server. All the modules dav, dav_svn and authz_svn are in place an running. Unfortunately., searching for the error in a search engine of my choice doesn't get me any further.
When accessing svn via a browser it still tells the version to be 1.7.5.x when do a 'svn help' it shows 1.8.3.x

After downgrading to 1.7.5 again, I get this:

```
Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: libsvn_repos-1.so.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Go to serverfault.com

Comment: ok. danke, anke. http://serverfault.com/questions/540873/problems-after-updating-svn-to-1-8-3-on-ubuntu-12-10-using-wandisco-package